# $\cos(x)$ strictly increasing on $(-\pi,0)$

Tags: real-analysis

How can one show that $f(x) =\cos(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(-\pi,0)$? That is, how can one show that $\sin(x)<0$ for all $x \in (-\pi,0)$ (as $f'(x)=-\sin(x)$) **rigorously**? Although I know that the image of $\sin$ on this interval is $(-1,0)$ and this should suffice, I'm not sure how to *prove* that this is the image.

Comment: I'd recommend using a Taylor series approximation to show that $\sin(x)<0$ on that domain.

Comment: @daOnlyBG to what degree what make sense?

Comment: Probably up to the third or fifth term; any term that has a positive sign. That way, the term serves as an upper bound to $\sin(x)$. Since that approximation alone is negative, and yet is still an upper bound, then you deduce that the real function *must* be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned, it suffices to show that $f'(x)>0$ on $(-\pi,0)$.  To this end, observe that (using the comment of @daOnlyBG)
$$f'(x)=-\sin(x) \geq \sum_{k=0}^{3}(-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!},$$
where the inequality comes from the series representation of $\sin(x)$.  Thus, $x \in (-\pi,0) \implies f'(x) > 0$.

Comment: $f'(x)\geq \pi-\frac{pi^3}{3!}+\frac{\pi^5}{5!}=0.524$ is not true for many $x\in(-\pi,0)$

Comment: Well this is the form of an answer I was looking for and I would appreciate if you could help me modify it for correctness if you disagree @JMoravitz

Comment: See my answer for more details, but in general, the inequality will depend on the value of $x$.  You seem to have simply plugged in $\pi$ in the place of $x$.  In particular, $f'(x)$ will be greater than a partial sum ending in a subtraction.  The question is then if that subtraction will be large enough to make it negative or not, hence why you need to consider the potential error for having stopped there.

Comment: I plugged in $x=-\pi$ since the lowest value $x$ can take is $-\pi$, but I'm not completely confident what I did was correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz is this edit now correct?

Answer (score 1):

(continuing from the other answerer's post having gotten to the question of how to show $\sin(x)$ is postive on the interval $(0,\pi)$)

Using the complex analysis definition of $\sin$ and power series expansions of $e^u$,

Let $x\in(0,\pi)$

Then $\sin(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+c_9(x)~~$ where $c_9(x)\in(-.09,.09)$.  Expand further if you wish to make the error range smaller.  The error range $c_n$ is $O(\frac{1}{n!})$.

For whatever $x$ you pick in the range, you will be able to find an $n$ such that the error range is smaller than the partial sum up to that point, showing that it is in fact positive on the entire interval.

Comment: Note the question @JMoravitz tagged with "real analysis"

Comment: Then skip the entry in the equations with $e^{ix}$ terms if it makes you feel better.  The definition of $\sin$ for the complex plane coincides with the definition for the reals, and the summation notation on should coincide with whatever strict definition you want to use for $\sin$ in a real analysis context.  If that is **not** how you define $\sin$, then pray tell, how DO you define it?  If not by the taylor series (which works in a complex *or* in a real case), or by the geometric interpretation, or by the unit-circle definition,

Answer (score -2):

Let $x'= -x$, then since $x \in (-\pi,0)$, $x' \in (0,\pi)$, and $\sin x' \in (0,1)$. Hence:

$\sin x = -\sin x' \in (-1,0)$.

Comment: But then the same question applies - how do you prove that $\sin(x') \in (0,1)$ for $x' \in (0,\pi)$?

Comment: By the definition of $\sin$?  if it is defined as opp/hyp, regardless which angle in $(0,\pi)$, the opposite side will be of positive length and so will the hypotenuse, so it will be positive.  Then by the triangle inequality, it can't be more than 1.  Equivalently, if you use the unit-circle definition you get the same result, sin of the angle will live in the positive y direction.

Comment: @JMoravitz This is not the definition of $\sin$ in a real analysis context. We can either define $\sin$ using the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ or with its series representation.

Comment: Surely there are whole classes of functions which satisfy that limit, so that definition doesn't make sense (for example the function $x$).  As for it's series representation, then that should work fine as well.  Show that it converges to a positive quantity given those input values.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry I meant using this limit, not to say that it is the only function that satisfies the limit. The definitions you have cited are not rigorous definitions whatsoever.

Comment: @JMoravitz as for your comment about the series representation, my question then reduces to *how* to do this.